# Converting hex to ascii

Tags: hex, ascii

I was wondering why when trying to convert a hexadecimal like `0x1C` on an online hexadecimal to ascii converter I get an empty string.  Likewise, when I use simple code it returns a weird symbol.  Yet when I try to convert something like `0x34` it works fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: See [this link](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html) for the list of Ascii table which clarifies printable & non-printable characters & [this link](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the full table with extended as well

Comment: Retagged: has nothing to do with C++.

Answer (score 1):

`0x1C` is the "file separator" character: it's a control (i.e. non-printable) character, and so when it's displayed you'll typically get some kind of substitute glyph displayed on your screen. On the other hand, `0x34` is the "4" character, and therefore is perfectly printable as is.

All of the ASCII characters before `0x20` (space) are non-printable control characters and will display the same behaviour as `0x1C`.

Answer (score 0):

0x1C is a file separator, so it won't show up as a "normal" symbol. I'd suggest looking at an ASCII table like [this one](http://www.asciitable.com/). Not everything is going to come out as an a-zA-Z0-9 symbol.

Comment: Great, I looked at the table as you said, however visual studio is showing me 0x13 as "L" instead of "19" what is what the table says, any ideas?

Comment: @user541597 0x13 won't show "19", 19 is the decimal equivalent to 0x13. The first 3 columns are equivalent codes just in different bases, so 0x13 is equivalent to 19 in decimal which is equivalent to 023 in octal. The actual character corresponding to 0x13 is "device control 3".